# Fragments in android displaying an error,Unable to add a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sign Up which consists of Two fragments. In the first fragment I have a button, When I click it i want to move to the next fragment. But I am struct with the code which is showing as error- Cannot resolve method add?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Button okButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Ok);

        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentSignupTwo fragmentSignupTwo = new FragmentSignupTwo();
                FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_register, fragmentSignupTwo);
                FragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Including the code to your question is helpful, but it would be even more helpful if you could just copy it directly inside your post instead of taking a screenshot next time ;).

Comment: so you're saying that `activity_register` is a fragment even that it has activity in it

Comment: No that is a basic Activity, and FagmentSignupone and FragmentSignupTwo are two fragments. the first one i included in the activity by using fragment with name attribute. Now when I click a button of fragment it should display the seccond fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `android.app.*` instead of `android.support.*` for fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Define a FrameLayout inside your Activity layout, with an id (ie. `@+id/container`) and pass that id to the add() method (ie `FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragmentSignupTwo)`).

Answer (score 0):

using android.app.* even did not work
 the error is at 
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_register,fragmentSignupTwo);
-error cannot resolve method add

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface
public interface FragmentChangeListener 
{
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment); 
}`enter code here`